# How can I tell when existentially quantified data constructors are needed to achieve my goals?

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Recently I implemented a type hierarchy similar to `Exception`. The gist of it is this:

```hs
class (Typeable a) => Hierarchy a where
    toHierarchy :: a -> HierarchyBase
    fromHierarchy :: HierarchyBase -> Maybe a

-- HierarchyBase
data HierarchyBase = forall h. (Hierarchy h) => HierarchyBase h
instance Hierarchy HierarchyBase where
    toHierarchy = id
    fromHierarchy = Just

-- MyType ⊂ HierarchyBase
data MyType = forall e. (Hierarchy h) => MyType h
instance Hierarchy MyType where
    toHierarchy x = HierarchyBase x
    fromHierarchy (HierarchyBase x) = cast x

-- SubType ⊂ MyType ⊂ HierarchyBase
data SubType = SubType
instance Hierarchy SubType where
    toHierarchy x = toHierarchy $ MyType x
    fromHierarchy (HierarchyBase x) = cast x >>= \(MyType x') -> cast x'

-- dispatchHierarchy automatically casts a type into any of its ancestors.
-- for instance, you can do any of these:
-- > disptachHierarchy (f :: HierarchyBase -> ...) SubType
-- > disptachHierarchy (f :: MyType        -> ...) SubType
-- > disptachHierarchy (f :: SubType       -> ...) SubType
hierarchyDispatch :: (Hierarchy a, Hierarchy a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
hierarchyDispatch f h = f . fromJust . fromHierarchy . toHierarchy $ h
```

This solution uses existentially quantified data constructors to define some *subtypeable* hierarchy types. I've tried to rewrite it without using existentials, but I didn't manage.

I understand that using existential quantifiers this way lets you *hide* the type variable used in a type constructor: the datatype doesn't depend on it, and I can see why that's necessary to define the `Hierarchy` typeclass and its instances.

However I don't understand when or why this feature is useful or necessary. Now, every time I get stuck on a type's kind when defining a typeclass or an instance, I feel that I have to try to use existential quantifiers. But it never worked so far. The problem was always somewhere else. And my code is cluttered with unnecessary existentials (think of the classical example of having `[Showable 1, Showable 'a']` instead of simply `[show 1, show 'a']`).

How can I tell when existentially quantified data constructors are needed or useful, as opposed to unnecessary overhead?

Comment: 99% of the time, the answer is "don't use existentials". They do very rarely come in handy, but it's absolutely the exception and not the norm. Perhaps you could explain a bit more what your `Hierarchy` snippet is intended to do. I can't really figure out the goal from the snippet given, but it looks like you're basically trying to re-design a Java-style class hierarchy in Haskell, and that's simply not productive. Haskell provides a different paradigm to work in, and trying to write traditional OOP class hierarchies is just fighting against all of the tools the language gives us.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: I wanted to define a hierarchy of types similar to the `Exception` hierarchy: I can call `disptachHierarchy (f :: HierarchyBase -> ()) SubType`, `disptachHierarchy (f :: MyType -> ()) SubType`, `disptachHierarchy (f :: SubType -> ()) SubType` and they will all work. I didn't really need this hierarchy, just did it in order to understand how the `Exception` hierarchy works.

Comment: What exception hierarchy are you talking about? This seems to be less about exceptions and more about OOP-style inheritance, which is what you *don't* want to mess around with in Haskell. (Even OOP languages tend to encourage solutions other than inheritance, such as composition, where possible.)

Comment: @chepner: I'm talking about the `Exception` typeclass, the `SomeException` type, the `catch` function and the exception hierarchy: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplification of existential datatypes to non-existentials follows from parametricity: the *in*ability to pattern match on types.

```
data Showable = forall a. Show a => Showable a
-- simplify: Show a is basically a -> String (ignoring showsPrec and showList)
data Showable' = forall a. Showable' a (a -> String)
-- simplify: because pattern matching on the type inside a Showable is not allowed,
-- the only thing that you can do with the a is pass it to the function
-- and the only thing you can do to the function is pass in the given a
data Showable'' = Showable'' String
-- now you realize a Showable type is mostly useless
```

But `Typeable` is much harder to deal with than `Show`. This is understandable: `Typeable a` essentially *means* "you can match the type `a` against patterns". Even if you give up the "open GADT" `TypeRep a` that comes with `Typeable` and keep e.g. just the `cast` operator, you get a higher-rank type:

```
data Object = forall a. Object a
-- simplify: because pattern matching on the type inside an Object is not allowed
-- the only thing you can do with the a is nothing
data Object' = Object' -- so Object is useless (just use ()!)

data Dynamic = forall a. Typeable a => Dynamic a
-- "simplify": weaken Typeable a to cast :: a -> forall b. Typeable b => Maybe b, then apply parametricity
data Dynamic' = Dynamic' (forall a. Typeable a => Maybe a)
-- but a) you lose the TypeRep and b) this is not exactly simpler
-- (*all* existential types have a higher-rank encoding anyway)
```

So existential types involving `Typeable` (including yours) *can't* be meaningfully simplified.

Existential types are also useful if you really can't control how many values of the quantified type you have, such as in

```
data Coyoneda f a = forall b. Coyoneda (f b) (b -> a)
```

Simplifying this type according to the scheme above requires you to "find the `b`s" in `f b` and preapply the `b -> a` to them, but `f` is not fixed so that's not possible. (When `f` is a `Functor` actually `Coyoneda f a ~= f a`, but there are still performance reasons for using `Coyoneda`.) The only way out is the generic-but-unhelpful higher-ranked translation:

```
data Coyoneda' f a = Coyoneda' (forall r. (forall b. f b -> (b -> a) -> r) -> r)
```

With those examples done, I think this is a good place to put the real answer to your question: it is nontrivial to simplify away an existential type, or even to tell when that is possible. There are some "obvious" markers for types that can't be simplified, and even types that can be simplified may look very different afterwards. For one last example of that kind, the following type came up for me recently. I used it to represent navigation on a non-planar surface:

```
data Map = forall pos. Map { -- an "associated type" kind of existential, where an existential is used to "create a type at runtime" such as in singletons
  mapInit :: pos,
  mapForward :: (pos, Facing) -> (pos, Facing), -- moving forward on a non-flat surface may change the direction of travel
  mapBacking :: pos -> Index -- "lower" a position to an index into a backing store
}
foldIntoTorus :: BackingStore -> Maybe Map
foldIntoCube  :: BackingStore -> Maybe Map
-- etc.
```

This type was easy to come up with: I thought of the cases and operations I needed to handle and wrote them down. However, the scheme for removing existentials actually applies pretty easily, and simplifies `Map` to

```
type Map' = Pos
-- infinite tree, where the root is the current position and each child is the position in the given direction
data Pos = Pos Index (Facing -> (Pos, Facing))
```

Is this encoding more or less intuitive? In some cases, the choice of whether to use an existential is more about what you find easy to think about, not necessity.

Comment: I'll have to re-read this multiple times in order to metabolize everything. But thanks, your answer is very well exhaustive.